# program to monitor other programs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, task

EDIT:::

I wonder if anyone has ever given this some thought or have some ideas about it. Like most of you I have multiple programs running at the same time. I have set up alert methods in each such that I get email alerts when a program stops or runs into errors. Now some of these programs use visual studio TaskFactory class to create parallel tasks and I have coded exception handling to handle errors. But I am sure some of you have encountered instances where a program /process will halt for some reason and unless you are constantly sitting at your pc and checking some log file, there is no way to know if the program is running at that time or not. 
so before many answer with...."Task Manager"...I wanted some intelligent ideas on ways of having your program notify you when it is stuck in some process or fails with some error an exception handler has not caught...if nobody runs into these types of cases then I guess I will just forget about it. Is there a way to interact with the task manager processes using visual studio, vb/C#?

Answer (score 1):

How does this differ from the basic Task Manager included in Windows?

If you want to make your own metrics to monitor you can create Performance Counters:  http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SetPerformanceCounters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Task Manager? Ctrl+Shift+Esc in Windows.

Comment: well yes, but how about one to only monitor your applications